# A question about$\text{ SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{e}\mathbb{Z})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $S=\left [\begin{array}[cc] 
&a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}\right ] \in \text{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{e}\mathbb{Z})$, which is congurent to $1 \text{ mod }p^{e}$. Write $S= 1 + p^{e}U$.

1. Show that $\text{Tr}(U) \equiv 0 \text { mod }p$
2. Show that $U \equiv U_{1} + U_{2} + \ldots + U_{k} \text{ mod }p$ such that $U_{i}^{2} = 0$
3. Show that, from this, we can assume $U^{2} = 0$

My attempt at it so far has been as follows:

$$S=\left [\begin{array}[cc] 
&a & b \\
c & d
\end{array} \right ] = \underbrace{\left [\begin{array}[cc] 
&1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right ]}_{1} + \underbrace{\left [\begin{array}[cc] 
&p^{e} & 0 \\
0 & p^{e}
\end{array} \right ]}_{p^{e}}\underbrace{ \left [\begin{array}[cc] 
&a' & b' \\
c' & d'
\end{array} \right ] }_{U}$$

$$\text{det}(S) = 1 = \text{det} \left (\underbrace{\left [\begin{array}[cc] 
&1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right ]}_{1} + \underbrace{\left [\begin{array}[cc] 
&p^{e} & 0 \\
0 & p^{e}
\end{array} \right ]}_{p^{e}}\underbrace{ \left [\begin{array}[cc] 
&a' & b' \\
c' & d'
\end{array} \right ] }_{U} \right )$$

$$= (1+a'p^{e})(1+d'p^{e}) - c'b'p^{2e}$$
$$= 1 +a'd'p^{2e} +a'p^{e} +d'p^{e} -c'b'p^{2e} =  1 $$

so

$$a'd'p^{e} +a'+b'-c'b'p^{e} = 0$$
$$a'+d' = (c'b' - a'd')p^{e}$$

the only thing theres possible is that

$$a'+b' \mid p^{e}$$

so $$a'+b' = \text{Tr}(U) \equiv 0 \text{ mod } p$$

from here we can write $U$ as

$$U = \left [\begin{array}[cc] \\
a' & b' \\
c' & pf - a'
\end{array} \right ]  $$

From here I make an explicit sum of $U_{i}'s$ where $U_{i}^{2} = 0$

$$U= \left [\begin{array}[cc] \\
a' & b' \\
c' & pf - a'
\end{array} \right ] = \left [ \begin{array}[cc] \\
a' & a' \\
-a' &- a'
\end{array} \right ] + \left [\begin{array}[cc] \\
0' & b'- a' \\
0 & 0
\end{array} \right ] + \left [\begin{array}[cc] \\
0 & 0 \\
c' + a' & 0
\end{array} \right ]  + \left [\begin{array}[cc] \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & pf
\end{array} \right ]   $$

All of these componants obviously satisfy $U_{i}^{2} = 0$. However im unsure whether this answers the question set in the first place, and moreover how to proceed to the third part.

Comment: @DietrichBurde could you maybe help me out with what the title could be?

Comment: A question about $\text{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{e}\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: Sorry.. this makes not much sense to me.. First, I guess, $e$ is a fixed positive integer. If we are working over $\Bbb Z/p^e\Bbb Z$, then $p^e\cdot U$ will give $0$, as $p^e=0$ there. Also, 'a matrix being congruent to $1$' was little hard to comprehend..